# [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: post.text.toLowerCase is not a function"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am getting this error. I am trying to filter my array with my searchbar (input)
I am doing search operation as computed.

```html
<div class="post"
    @click="getData(post.header,post.text)"
    v-for="(post) in searchList"
    v-bind:item="post"
    v-bind:key="post._id"
    >
```

Computed Property

```js
computed:{
  searchList() {
    return this.posts.filter(post => {
      return post.text.toLowerCase().includes(this.lookfor.toLowerCase())
    })
  }
},
```

Please help me, Thanks

[This is where i am calling computed function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chjB2.png)

[This is computed property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBZKO.png)

[This is error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQtsh.png)

Comment: It seems that for at least one of your `posts`, `post.text` is not a string. How about adding some simple debugging like this in your `filter` callback ~ `console.log(typeof post.text, post.text)`

Comment: you could return simply `return post.text && post.text.toLowerCase().includes(this.lookfor.toLowerCase())`

Comment: @Jhecht it's unlikely that will work. If `post.text` was `null` or `undefined`, the error message would be different. That being said, perhaps `post.text` is Boolean `false` for some records

Comment: You need to check your post.text. Only types of `String` have a method `.toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that for at least one of your posts, `post.text` is not a string.

The simplest idea would be to filter out these non-strings

```js
computed: {
  searchList () {
    const search = this.lookfor.toLowerCase()
    return this.posts.filter(post => typeof post.text === 'string'
      && post.text.toLowerCase().includes(search))
  }
}
```

---

Alternately, you could use a newer feature like [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```js
return post.text.toLowerCase().?includes(search)
```

Comment: you could also just run `post.text && post.text.toLowerCase && post.text.toLowerCase().includes(search)`

Comment: @Jhecht why perform three evaluations when two gets the job done?

Comment: I've seen some codebases that dislike the use of typeof unless absolutely necessary (my previous job being one of them). Should also be noted that you can also option chaining if the target browsers support it (or if you're using babel)

Comment: @Jhecht do you have a reason for disliking it? There are no applicable warnings on the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) (just one for old Internet Explorer). Also, did you mean [_"optional chaining"_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)? If so, then yes, that's an option. I'll add it to my answer

Comment: I have no strong feelings about it one way or another. Just putting the information out there. Some people don't like using typeof, so just checking to see if the function exists before calling it would be fine. btw in yur example it should be `post.text?.toLowerCase().includes(search)` since we're not sure about the text property having the `toLowerCase` method.

Comment: @Jhecht What we are sure of is that `post.text` is **not** [_nullish_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/nullish), otherwise the error message would be different. It's just not a string so perhaps a `Boolean` or `Object`. With that in mind, this is the same as the _`someNonExistentMethod`_ example from the _Optional Chaining_ documentation